# Why does `url_to_postid` return 0 when testing `page_for_posts` Page?

Tags: posts, functions, pages, customization

If I set **Reading Settings** > **Posts Page** (in other words, the `page_for_posts` option) to a static page, and then attempt to pass its URL through `url_to_postid()` it will return `0` - why is it?

I understand that it's technically no longer a static/post page, but is the posts page, however that page *still has an ID* and I still need to get at it. Funny enough, I need to get the ID in order to test if it *is* the same value as `page_for_posts`. I can't use the `0` returned from the url_to_postid function because 0 can be returned for a number of reasons.

Does anyone know how I can test the current URL to get its ID, when it's set to the `page_for_posts` page?

Comment: I also get this issue, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

The reason you get 0 back is because of the test at the end of the function:

```
if ( ! empty( $query->posts ) && $query->is_singular )
    return $query->post->ID;
else
    return 0;
```

The posts page doesn't pass the `is_singular` test so 0 is returned.

If you have a URL and want to know if it's the posts page, you can match it against the permalink returned from `get_permalink` when passed the `page_for_posts` option:

```
$page_for_posts_url = get_permalink( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) );
if( $current_url == $page_for_posts_url ) echo 'this is the page for posts!';
```

Answer (score 1):

**The posts page is not a page**. For example, set a page with a page template as your posts page, and you will not get the page template. Instead, you'll likely see `archive.php` or `index.php`, because the main loop/query isn't loading a page, it's loading the primary post archive.

Hence this code:

```
if ( ! empty( $query->posts ) && $query->is_singular )
    return $query->post->ID;
else
    return 0;
```

When on the posts page, `is_singular` is false, because it's an archive page, not a single post page

Thus, there is no post at that URL, and thus `0` is appropriate, because it's an error code indicating no posts.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look a this function, it may be useful.
[WP function get_page_by_path()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_path)

Comment: Please explain _why_ this answer is helpful.